# Conflict with duplicate JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, conflict

In a project, on a dynamically generated page, the same JavaScript functions are being loaded several times. That makes a conflict and none of the functions work. To be more precise, several tables are being loaded and some rows of those tables are expandable. When several tables are being loaded and all those tables use the same template, the JavaScript code is being duplicated several times in the same page which makes it impossible for those functions to work. Is there a way to either fix this for all the tables or at least for the first one only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have code? or do we have to guess at what you did?

Comment: If you're defining functions in HTML elements, you're doing it wrong. Define them once at the top of the page and call them when you need them. Don't define them every time you need to use them.

Comment: Does the code really matter? The conflict is that the same code is being repeated several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix this in a number of ways:

Use anonymous javascript functions to take these variables outside the default namespace.

Recode your javascript so it works properly and can only be loaded once, but still apply to every table it should apply to.  Consider using classes and writing a jquery plugin. <- Do this one.  Once you get it working you can move it to an external file so that the user's browser can cache it, and speed up page loading times.

Attach a unique identifier to your javascript functions.  <- Don't do this one, it's just a headache.  It makes things hard to cache, and requires you to dynamically generate the javascript on every page!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the name of the javascript functions so that they include the row's unique identifier.  That way they all stay unique and the rows can still call them.